# OrientDB: Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.MOVE VERTEX

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientdb community edition 1.7.9 on mac osx.

Database Info:

> DISTRIBUTED CONFIGURATION: none (OrientDB is running in standalone
>   mode)

**DATABASE PROPERTIES**

---

> NAME | VALUE|
>
> Name | null |
>
> Version | 9  |
>
> Date format  | yyyy-MM-dd |
>
> Datetime format | yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss |
>
> Timezone | Asia/xxxx |
>
> Locale Country | US |
>
> Locale Language | en |
>
> Charset | UTF-8 |
>
> Schema RID | #0:1 |
>
> Index Manager RID | #0:2 |
>
> Dictionary RID | null |

**Command flow:**

```
  create cluster xyz physical default default append

  alter class me add cluster xyz

  move vertex #1:2 to cluster:xyz
```

**Studio UI throw the following error:**

> 014-10-22 14:59:33:043 SEVE Internal server error:
>   com.orientechnologies.orient.core.command.OCommandExecutorNotFoundException:
>   Cannot find a command executor for the command request: sql.MOVE
>   VERTEX #1:2 TO CLUSTER:xyz [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]

Console return a record as select does. I do not see error in the log.

I am planning a critical feature by using altering cluster for selected records.

Could anyone help on this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

move vertex command is not supported in 1.7.x 
you have to use switch to 2.0-M2

Comment: Thank you. I didn't noticed the version conflict.

Answer (score 0):

The OrientDB Console is a Java Application made to work against OrientDB databases and Server instances.
[more](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Console-Commands)